# How do I sort an Excel 2010 pivot table based on a subset of the data it contains?

Tags: sorting, ssas, pivot-table, excel-2010

I have an Excel 2010 pivot table that has categories and a count measure as the data. Those categories then have a date dimension nested underneath, filtered to show only the last two months.

When I sort the categories, I am sorting them by the total of the count measure across both June and July, in descending order.

Can anyone suggest how I can sort the categories based on the June data alone, as opposed to the total for both June and July?

Thanks!

Comment: Not programming related.

Comment: If that's the case, then why are there other questions on here related to SSAS and pivot tables?

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is not related to Sql Server Analysis Services. SSAS provides multidimensional data that is also used by pivot tables as datasource. So that's why you have seen pivot table questions here. But they are not Excel related.

Anyway, i want to try to answer your question. As far as i understand your question, changing the order of the dimensions in your pivot table will be sufficient to achieve your goal. Add the date dimension to the pivot table first and then the category dimension to get your data grouped by date (month). You may then sort by categories to get the result you want.

Hope this help.